Calculating Visitor Durations in R Data Frame: How to Calculate Time in Agency, Rooms, and Waiting Periods?
I have a data frame in R with data from an agency. Visitors (ID) enter the agency (CREATE), are then called into different rooms (CALL), and leave these rooms (DISCHARGE). Now, I want to calculate how long someone is in the agency overall, how long they are in a room, and how long they wait between two rooms. I have created an example data.frame where the last three columns already contain the desired result, which I ultimately want to achieve. These columns do not exist in the actual data frame.
For diff_since_create, it simply needs to calculate the time since CREATE for each row within an ID.
The variable time_in_room should represent the minutes for an id since the last 'CALL' event. This indicates the time a visitor spends in a room. For the initial 'CALL', this time starts at 0 and ends with a 'DISCHARGE' event.
The variable time_waiting should represent the minutes for an id since the last 'DISCHARGE' event. This indicates the time a visitor (identified by id) spends outside of a room.
Multiple lines can occur between a 'CALL' and 'DISCHARGE' event, or between a 'DISCHARGE' and a 'CALL' event.
Does anyone have an idea how to calculate the last 3 rows with R? I would greatly appreciate your help!
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time = structure(c(1713164400, 
1713164700, 1713165000, 1713165600, 1713165720, 1713165780, 1713166200, 
1713166500, 1713167100, 1713164400, 1713164700, 1713165000, 1713165600, 
1713166020, 1713166200, 1713166500, 1713166620, 1713167100), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), action = c("create", "call", "discharge", 
"call", "work", "work", "discharge", "call", "discharge", "create", 
"call", "discharge", "call", "work", "discharge", "call", "work", 
"discharge"), room = c("", "room 1", "room 1", "room 2", "room 2", 
"room 2", "room 2", "room 3", "room 3", "", "room 1", "room 1", 
"room 2", "room 2", "room 2", "room 3", "room 3", "room 3"), 
    diff_since_create = c(0L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 30L, 35L, 
    45L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 35L, 37L, 45L), time_in_room = c("na", 
    "0", "5", "0", "2", "3", "10", "0", "10", "na", "0", "5", 
    "0", "7", "10", "0", "2", "10"), time_waiting = c(0L, 5L, 
    0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")


both id's discharge room 1 at 9:10 and call room 2 at 9:20, but in id 1 time_in_room is 5, while for id 2 it's 10, why? And the first four "call room x" lines have time_in_room 0, but the last three have time_in_room 10/7/5, corresponding to the time since the prior line. I'm unclear on the distinction.

Oh sorry, I made a mistake. Please use the updated example data.

df |>
  mutate(dsc = (time - min(time))/lubridate::dminutes(), .by = id, 
         .after = diff_since_create) |>
  mutate(tir = if_else(action == "create", NA_real_,
                       (time - min(time))/lubridate::dminutes()), 
         .after = time_in_room,
         .by = c(id, room)) |>
  mutate(last_disch = if_else(action %in% c("discharge", "create"), time, NA_POSIXct_)) |>
  group_by(id) |> fill(last_disch) |> ungroup() |>
  mutate(tw = if_else(action == "call", (time - last_disch)/lubridate::dminutes(), 0),
         .after = time_waiting) |>
  select(-last_disch)

Result (This mostly matches. I presume row 14 diff_since_create was meant to be 27.)
# A tibble: 18 × 10
      id time                action    room     diff_since_create   dsc time_in_room   tir time_waiting    tw
   <int> <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>                <int> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>        <int> <dbl>
 1     1 2024-04-15 00:00:00 create    ""                       0     0 na              NA            0     0
 2     1 2024-04-15 00:05:00 call      "room 1"                 5     5 0                0            5     5
 3     1 2024-04-15 00:10:00 discharge "room 1"                10    10 5                5            0     0
 4     1 2024-04-15 00:20:00 call      "room 2"                20    20 0                0           10    10
 5     1 2024-04-15 00:22:00 work      "room 2"                22    22 2                2            0     0
 6     1 2024-04-15 00:23:00 work      "room 2"                23    23 3                3            0     0
 7     1 2024-04-15 00:30:00 discharge "room 2"                30    30 10              10            0     0
 8     1 2024-04-15 00:35:00 call      "room 3"                35    35 0                0            5     5
 9     1 2024-04-15 00:45:00 discharge "room 3"                45    45 10              10            0     0
10     2 2024-04-15 00:00:00 create    ""                       0     0 na              NA            0     0
11     2 2024-04-15 00:05:00 call      "room 1"                 5     5 0                0            5     5
12     2 2024-04-15 00:10:00 discharge "room 1"                10    10 5                5            0     0
13     2 2024-04-15 00:20:00 call      "room 2"                20    20 0                0           10    10
14     2 2024-04-15 00:27:00 work      "room 2"                20    27 7                7            0     0
15     2 2024-04-15 00:30:00 discharge "room 2"                30    30 10              10            0     0
16     2 2024-04-15 00:35:00 call      "room 3"                35    35 0                0            5     5
17     2 2024-04-15 00:37:00 work      "room 3"                37    37 2                2            0     0
18     2 2024-04-15 00:45:00 discharge "room 3"                45    45 10              10            0     0


Didn't know it was possible to use the .after and .before arguments within mutate. Good!

Slightly different tidyverse take with dplyr::lag:
libray(tidyverse)
conflicted::conflict_prefer("lag", winner = "dplyr") # or just `dplyr::lag`
# ----------------

df <- df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = id, 
    visit_id = cumsum(if_else(action == "call", 1, 0)),
    diff_since_create = as.duration(time - min(time)),
    time_waiting = if_else(visit_id == lag(visit_id) + 1, time - lag(time), as.duration(NA))) %>% 
  
  mutate(.by = c(id, visit_id), time_in_room = as.duration(time - min(time))) %>% 
  
    select(id:room, diff_since_create, time_in_room, time_waiting)

Output:
# A tibble: 18 × 7
      id time                action    room     diff_since_create   time_in_room       time_waiting      
   <int> <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>    <Duration>          <Duration>         <Duration>        
 1     1 2024-04-15 04:00:00 create    ""       0s                  0s                 NA                
 2     1 2024-04-15 04:05:00 call      "room 1" 300s (~5 minutes)   0s                 300s (~5 minutes) 
 3     1 2024-04-15 04:10:00 discharge "room 1" 600s (~10 minutes)  300s (~5 minutes)  NA                
 4     1 2024-04-15 04:20:00 call      "room 2" 1200s (~20 minutes) 0s                 600s (~10 minutes)
 5     1 2024-04-15 04:22:00 work      "room 2" 1320s (~22 minutes) 120s (~2 minutes)  NA                
 6     1 2024-04-15 04:23:00 work      "room 2" 1380s (~23 minutes) 180s (~3 minutes)  NA                
 7     1 2024-04-15 04:30:00 discharge "room 2" 1800s (~30 minutes) 600s (~10 minutes) NA                
 8     1 2024-04-15 04:35:00 call      "room 3" 2100s (~35 minutes) 0s                 300s (~5 minutes) 
 9     1 2024-04-15 04:45:00 discharge "room 3" 2700s (~45 minutes) 600s (~10 minutes) NA                
10     2 2024-04-15 04:00:00 create    ""       0s                  0s                 NA                
11     2 2024-04-15 04:05:00 call      "room 1" 300s (~5 minutes)   0s                 300s (~5 minutes) 
12     2 2024-04-15 04:10:00 discharge "room 1" 600s (~10 minutes)  300s (~5 minutes)  NA                
13     2 2024-04-15 04:20:00 call      "room 2" 1200s (~20 minutes) 0s                 600s (~10 minutes)
14     2 2024-04-15 04:27:00 work      "room 2" 1620s (~27 minutes) 420s (~7 minutes)  NA                
15     2 2024-04-15 04:30:00 discharge "room 2" 1800s (~30 minutes) 600s (~10 minutes) NA                
16     2 2024-04-15 04:35:00 call      "room 3" 2100s (~35 minutes) 0s                 300s (~5 minutes) 
17     2 2024-04-15 04:37:00 work      "room 3" 2220s (~37 minutes) 120s (~2 minutes)  NA                
18     2 2024-04-15 04:45:00 discharge "room 3" 2700s (~45 minutes) 600s (~10 minutes) NA  

Or, as @Jon Spring opted, in minutes:
> mutate(df, across(where(is.duration), \(x) x/dminutes()))
# A tibble: 18 × 7
      id time                action    room     diff_since_create time_in_room time_waiting
   <int> <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>                <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1 2024-04-15 04:00:00 create    ""                       0            0           NA
 2     1 2024-04-15 04:05:00 call      "room 1"                 5            0            5
 3     1 2024-04-15 04:10:00 discharge "room 1"                10            5           NA
 4     1 2024-04-15 04:20:00 call      "room 2"                20            0           10
 5     1 2024-04-15 04:22:00 work      "room 2"                22            2           NA
 6     1 2024-04-15 04:23:00 work      "room 2"                23            3           NA
 7     1 2024-04-15 04:30:00 discharge "room 2"                30           10           NA
 8     1 2024-04-15 04:35:00 call      "room 3"                35            0            5
 9     1 2024-04-15 04:45:00 discharge "room 3"                45           10           NA
10     2 2024-04-15 04:00:00 create    ""                       0            0           NA
11     2 2024-04-15 04:05:00 call      "room 1"                 5            0            5
12     2 2024-04-15 04:10:00 discharge "room 1"                10            5           NA
13     2 2024-04-15 04:20:00 call      "room 2"                20            0           10
14     2 2024-04-15 04:27:00 work      "room 2"                27            7           NA
15     2 2024-04-15 04:30:00 discharge "room 2"                30           10           NA
16     2 2024-04-15 04:35:00 call      "room 3"                35            0            5
17     2 2024-04-15 04:37:00 work      "room 3"                37            2           NA
18     2 2024-04-15 04:45:00 discharge "room 3"                45           10           NA


Looks like you calculated diff_since_create but omit from output.
